# Get Specific Area From Image

Tags: matlab, select, image-processing, area

I would like to ask a question about get specific area from image. For example, there is a non-geometric object on carpet. And i would like to select this area because in the next steps i will take a instance from non-geometric object and carpet.Instances should be just taken from object and carpet.

I tried to handle it with create square on object but in this situation i have object and carpet.

How can i do it or any information about that?

(I am using Matlab, if there is good practice in Matlab, it will so good...)

Thanks

Comment: This question is difficult (if not impossible) to answer. Can you please add some information on what objects there are (ideally with an example image), how you find and recognize the objects (can you add the MATLAB code?). How did you create this square object and what is not working with that?

Comment: I can draw a rectangle with "getrect" command so i have 4 points about rectangle. But with this command i have to select object and carpet. But i just want to select object.

I cant add example image because of my reputation. You can image like that there is a white textured carpet and on the carpet light dark object. And it is a pistachio. I would like to select just my pistachio not with carpet.
Thanks

Comment: I can help you but your question is so ambiguous. Please explain precisely and clearly. Try to use real objects to explain. may it help us.

Comment: Firstly thank you, i try to explain more clearly. Now we have two elements on image; first one is white textured carpet and second one is a pistachio. I would like to select just pistachio from image because i will get some feature from pistachio. With these features i will try to multiclass classification for seperate which one is pistachio and carpet.But you know pistachio not clearly rectangle form. Because of that if i can select or draw a border around the pistachio, i can get more useful feature. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this question, i can suggest to search on segmentation. If you are using Matlab, these links will be very helpful;

1. http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfreehand.html
2. http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/roi-based-processing.html

Thanks